# How do i expand several circles in canvas (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas

My code draws random circles on a canvas. I want to make it so that the **circles expand** to a certain point before **disappearing**, but I can't seem to figure out the expanding and disappearing part.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <style type="text/css">
           
          #canvas{
      display:inline;
      margins:auto;
      background-color:lightblue;  
                }
    
          </style>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="700" ></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
            
          function randomize(){
    
      var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+5;
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+50;
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+50;
      drawCircle(x,y,radius);  
    }
    function drawCircle(x,y,radius){
     
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fill();
    }
    
    var intervall = setInterval(randomize,1000);
    
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code shows no attempt at all that relates to the expanding or disappearing. You should show your efforts. BTW: the indentation of your code is ... bad.

Answer (score 0):

## How to define a circle

In order to define a circle you need to know the coordinates of its center (C) and its radius (r).

## Making a circle disappear

In order to make a circl disappear you just draw over it with the background's pattern (in this specific case, the background color).

## Expanding

An expanded circle has the same center as its earlier self, so, you will just need to draw a circle with the same center, but greater radius.

## Gradual expanding

Let's say you have a circle with center C and radius r. Let's say that you want it to expand by 10 every 0.1 seconds, doing this 15 times. If so:

```
let index = 0;
let myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (index < 15) drawCircle(x, y, r += 10);
    else {
        //draw a circle centered at x, y, with r as radius but with background color
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 100);
```

You should make color as an optional parameter to your drawCircle which will make clearing circles extremely easy.